# After successfull api call not entering into the function in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```
download() {
    let singlecontract = this.state.singlecontract; 
    let data = singlecontract.contract.html;
    let token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    ContractAction._generatePDF(data,function(data) {
        var wnd = window.open("http://172.104.167.150:9082/contracts/downloadpdf?filename="+data.filename+"&access_token=" + token, "_blank");
        console.log(wnd);
        console.log(data);
    });   
}
```

After successfull _generatePdf it is not entering into the function not able to open in other window. and i am not able to console the values also not entering into the function

Comment: What is _generatePDF? A call to an API? Your own function? How are you sure that it generates it successfully?

Comment: yes, I am getting successfull response from success response only i will get filename

Comment: Okay, can you answer my other questions too? :) Also, do you get any errors in console?

Comment: no i am not able to get any error in console

Comment: https://www.useloom.com/share/d350aed716b84319ac9e22c4baa74f9c